# How to simplify repeated commands in the cmd terminal?

Tags: windows, performance, batch-file

I wrote a number of repetitive command lines like the one below, maybe there is input from others to simplify the command? as simple as possible.

```
@echo off
:stro
cls
echo. 
echo    Enter you term:
echo    ++++++++++++++++++++++
echo    1) Command Prompt (CMD)
echo    2) Power Shell
echo    3) Exit
echo.   
set /p kod=
if %kod% == 1 goto cmde
if %kod% == 2 goto pwsl
if %kod% == 3 goto exitx  
:exitx
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "tuntu.vbs"
echo speech.speak "thank you for use me. i hope you have a nice day. bye bye" >> "tuntu.vbs"
attrib +h "tuntu.vbs"
start tuntu.vbs
pause
attrib -h "tuntu.vbs"
del tuntu.vbs
exit
:cmde
start cmd
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "tuntu.vbs"
echo speech.speak "you choice is number %kod% and you open command prompt CMD"  >> "tuntu.vbs"
attrib +h "tuntu.vbs"
start tuntu.vbs
pause
attrib -h "tuntu.vbs"
del tuntu.vbs
goto stro
:pwsl
start powershell
echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "tuntu.vbs"
echo speech.speak "you choice is number %kod% and you open Power shell"  >> "tuntu.vbs"
attrib +h "tuntu.vbs"
start tuntu.vbs
pause
attrib -h "tuntu.vbs"
del tuntu.vbs
goto stro
```

Then I want a command line that is simple and does not contain repetitive and boring sentences. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the `vbs` script just once (use a parameter instead of hardcoding the text):

Your code then shortens to:

```
@echo off

(echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice"^)
echo speech.speak WScript.Arguments(0^))>"speak.vbs"
attrib +h speak.vbs
set "say=cscript /nologo speak.vbs"

:stro
cls
echo. 
echo    Enter you term:
echo    ++++++++++++++++++++++
echo    1) Command Prompt (CMD)
echo    2) Power Shell
echo    3) Exit
echo.   

choice /c 123
set kod=%errorlevel%
goto :label%kod%

:label3
%say% "thank you for using me. i hope you have a nice day. bye bye"
exit /b

:label1
start cmd
%say% "your choice is number %kod% and you open command prompt CMD"  
goto stro

:label2
start powershell
%say% "your choice is number %kod% and you open Power shell"
goto stro
```

I also replaced your `set /p` to `choice`, because `choice` handles user input and prevents invalid inputs.

Comment: great, but I'm still confused by using `/nologo` on the line above. what line represents?

Comment: the `/nologo` supresses the logo (the two lines `Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host...` and `Copyright (C) Microsoft...`)

Comment: before I assumed it was related to the voice that was spoken. :) Thank you for the code line